# how do I put loop into html table?

Tags: php, html, loops, for-loop

foreach($matches as $match){ echo match[1]."-".match[2];}

I want `match[1]` and `match[2]` value should be displayed in an html table with two columns. for example

```
Name    |   Percent
--------|-----------
Mathew  |   95%
```

where mathew is `match[1]` and percent is `match[2]`

How I add html tags in between and for your info there were about 50 names.

Comment: Your matches array cannot do the thing you want. Do you pull them from database?

Answer (score 5):

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Percent</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($matches as $match): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php print $match[1]; ?></td>
    <td><?php print $match[2]; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Be careful that you really mean match[1] and match[2] and not match[0] and match[1]... the first element in a PHP array is 0.

Comment: If `$matches` came from `preg_match_all(..., ..., $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)`, then the subgroup indices start with 1. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<?php
foreach($matches as $match) {
?>
<tr><td><?php echo $match[1]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $match[2]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: but this is a loop so there are more rows

Comment: Apart from forgetting the table headers, I don't see what's wrong in this...they're printing rows in loop...

Answer (score 0):

Your matches array cannot do the thing you want. I guess you are pulling the data from the database.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM `db_table` ";
$result= mysql_result($query);
?>
<table>
while($matches = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
      <tr>
        <?php
        foreach($matches AS $match) {
        ?>
        <td><?php echo $match[0]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $match[1]; ?></td>        
        <?php
        }
        ?>
      </tr>

<?php
}
?>   
</table>
```